# Nested view is slowing down performance, Looking for a way to improve performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQl server and I Have created a  view that is calling data from another view and performance is very slow. is there a way to improve performance?

First View is ( this view is used to join tables and create flags)

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[VW_MCCSR_FLAGS_MP] AS 

    SELECT TB2.*,
    ----FLAGS FOR CSV (GF1)
    CASE WHEN TB2.PAR_UL_01     IS NOT NULL AND TB2.ROW_ITEM = 'CSV (GF1)' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CSV_GF1_PAR_UL_01_FLAG,
    CASE WHEN TB2.NONPAR_UL_01  IS NOT NULL AND TB2.ROW_ITEM = 'CSV (GF1)' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CSV_GF1_NONPAR_UL_01_FLAG,
    CASE WHEN TB2.PAR_UL_19     IS NOT NULL AND TB2.ROW_ITEM = 'CSV (GF1)' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CSV_GF1_PAR_UL_19_FLAG,
    CASE WHEN TB2.NONPAR_UL_19  IS NOT NULL AND TB2.ROW_ITEM = 'CSV (GF1)' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CSV_GF1_NONPAR_UL_19_FLAG,
    CASE WHEN TB2.VUL_19        IS NOT NULL AND TB2.ROW_ITEM = 'CSV (GF1)' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CSV_GF1_VUL_19_FLAG,
    CASE WHEN TB2.UL_26         IS NOT NULL AND TB2.ROW_ITEM = 'CSV (GF1)' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CSV_GF1_UL_26_FLAG,
    CASE WHEN TB2.UL_67         IS NOT NULL AND TB2.ROW_ITEM = 'CSV (GF1)' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CSV_GF1_UL_67_FLAG,
    CASE WHEN TB2.UL_89         IS NOT NULL AND TB2.ROW_ITEM = 'CSV (GF1)' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CSV_GF1_UL_89_FLAG,
    CASE WHEN TB2.UL_94         IS NOT NULL AND TB2.ROW_ITEM = 'CSV (GF1)' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CSV_GF1_UL_94_FLAG,
    CASE WHEN TB2.VUL_94        IS NOT NULL AND TB2.ROW_ITEM = 'CSV (GF1)' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CSV_GF1_VUL_94_FLAG,
    CASE WHEN TB2.UL_102        IS NOT NULL AND TB2.ROW_ITEM = 'CSV (GF1)' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CSV_GF1_UL_102_FLAG

    FROM

    (
    SELECT DISTINCT 'CSV' AS REPORT_NAME, 'CSV (GF1)'   AS ROW_ITEM,
    CASE WHEN TB1.GL_REINSURANCE_CLASS_CODE IS NULL  AND TB1.GL_Legal_ID_BK  = 1      AND  TB1.US_SOE_Group_Code LIKE  'UL'  AND TB1.Par_Code  = 4
         THEN SUM(TB1.Cash_Surrender_Value_Amt) END  AS PAR_UL_01,

    CASE WHEN TB1.GL_REINSURANCE_CLASS_CODE IS NULL  AND TB1.GL_Legal_ID_BK  = 1      AND  TB1.US_SOE_Group_Code LIKE  'UL'  AND TB1.Par_Code  = 2
         THEN SUM(TB1.Cash_Surrender_Value_Amt) END  AS NONPAR_UL_01,

    CASE WHEN TB1.GL_REINSURANCE_CLASS_CODE IS NULL  AND TB1.GL_Legal_ID_BK  = 19     AND  TB1.US_SOE_Group_Code LIKE  'UL'  AND TB1.Par_Code  = 4
         THEN SUM(TB1.Cash_Surrender_Value_Amt) END  AS PAR_UL_19,

    CASE WHEN TB1.GL_REINSURANCE_CLASS_CODE IS NULL  AND TB1.GL_Legal_ID_BK  = 19     AND  TB1.US_SOE_Group_Code LIKE  'UL'  AND TB1.Par_Code  = 2
         THEN SUM(TB1.Cash_Surrender_Value_Amt) END  AS NONPAR_UL_19,

    CASE WHEN TB1.GL_REINSURANCE_CLASS_CODE IS NULL  AND TB1.GL_Legal_ID_BK  = 19     AND  TB1.US_SOE_Group_Code LIKE  'VUL' AND TB1.Par_Code  = 2
         THEN (SUM(TB1.Cash_Surrender_Value_Amt) - SUM(TB1.SEPERATE_ACCOUNT_VALUE)) END  AS VUL_19,

    CASE WHEN TB1.GL_REINSURANCE_CLASS_CODE IS NULL  AND TB1.GL_Legal_ID_BK  = 26     AND  TB1.US_SOE_Group_Code LIKE  'UL'  AND TB1.Par_Code  = 2
         THEN 0 END  AS UL_26,

    CASE WHEN TB1.GL_REINSURANCE_CLASS_CODE IS NULL  AND TB1.GL_Legal_ID_BK  = 94     AND  TB1.US_SOE_Group_Code LIKE  'UL'  AND TB1.Par_Code  = 2
         THEN (SUM(TB1.Cash_Surrender_Value_Amt) / 0.09) END  AS UL_67,

    CASE WHEN TB1.GL_REINSURANCE_CLASS_CODE IS NULL  AND TB1.GL_Legal_ID_BK  = 89     AND  TB1.US_SOE_Group_Code LIKE  'UL'  AND TB1.Par_Code  = 2
         THEN SUM(TB1.Cash_Surrender_Value_Amt) END  AS UL_89,

    CASE WHEN TB1.GL_REINSURANCE_CLASS_CODE IS NULL  AND TB1.GL_Legal_ID_BK  = 94     AND  TB1.US_SOE_Group_Code LIKE  'UL'  AND TB1.Par_Code  = 2
         THEN SUM(TB1.Cash_Surrender_Value_Amt) END  AS UL_94,

    CASE WHEN TB1.GL_REINSURANCE_CLASS_CODE IS NULL  AND TB1.GL_Legal_ID_BK  = 94     AND  TB1.US_SOE_Group_Code LIKE  'VUL' AND TB1.Par_Code  = 2
         THEN (SUM(TB1.Cash_Surrender_Value_Amt) - SUM(TB1.SEPERATE_ACCOUNT_VALUE))  END  AS VUL_94,

    CASE WHEN TB1.GL_REINSURANCE_CLASS_CODE IS NULL  AND TB1.GL_Legal_ID_BK  = 102    AND  TB1.US_SOE_Group_Code LIKE  'UL'   AND TB1.Par_Code = 2
         THEN SUM(TB1.Cash_Surrender_Value_Amt) END  AS UL_102

    FROM 
    (SELECT distinct PF.POLICY_SID, PF.Cash_Surrender_Value_Amt ,CAST(PD.GL_Legal_ID_BK AS INT) AS GL_Legal_ID_BK,PD.US_SOE_Group_Code , CAST(PD.Par_Code AS INT) AS Par_Code
    ,CAST(CD.GL_REINSURANCE_CLASS_CODE AS INT) AS GL_REINSURANCE_CLASS_CODE
    , TBL1.FUND_BALANCE_AMT AS SEPERATE_ACCOUNT_VALUE

    FROM POLICY_FACT PF
    INNER JOIN Policy_DIM PD ON PF.Policy_SID = PD.Policy_SID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT crf.policy_sid , crf.coverage_sid FROM dbo.Coverage_rider_fact crf 
                     WHERE CRF.Reporting_period_sid = (SELECT  b.DATE_SID 
                                                        FROM 
                                                        [VSTPODS_US].[dbo].[REF_EXTRACT_MONTH] A
                                                        INNER JOIN 
                                                            [dbo].date_dim b
                                                        ON 
                                                            SUBSTRING(CAST(b.date_sid AS VARCHAR(8)),1,6) = A.EXTRACT_MONTH
                                                            WHERE  A.CURR_IND=1 AND B.Last_Day_of_the_Month_Ind = 1)
                                                        )  CURF 
                     ON PD.Policy_SID = CURF.POLICY_SID

    LEFT OUTER JOIN COVERAGE_DIM CD ON CURF.Coverage_SID = CD.Coverage_SID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT FF.policy_sid, FF.FUND_BALANCE_AMT,FD.Fund_Account_Type_Code FROM 
                     dbo.Fund_Account_Fact FF 
                     INNER JOIN dbo.Fund_Account_dim FD ON FF.Fund_Account_sid = FD.Fund_Account_sid
                     WHERE FD.Fund_Account_Type_Code = 'S' AND
                     FF.Reporting_Period_SID = (SELECT  b.DATE_SID 
                                                        FROM 
                                                        [VSTPODS_US].[dbo].[REF_EXTRACT_MONTH] A
                                                        INNER JOIN 
                                                            [dbo].date_dim b
                                                        ON 
                                                            SUBSTRING(CAST(b.date_sid AS VARCHAR(8)),1,6) = A.EXTRACT_MONTH
                                                            WHERE  A.CURR_IND=1 AND B.Last_Day_of_the_Month_Ind = 1)
                     ) TBL1 ON TBL1.Policy_sid = PF.Policy_SID

        WHERE PF.Reporting_Period_SID = (SELECT  b.DATE_SID 
                                                        FROM 
                                                        [VSTPODS_US].[dbo].[REF_EXTRACT_MONTH] A
                                                        INNER JOIN 
                                                            [dbo].date_dim b
                                                        ON 
                                                            SUBSTRING(CAST(b.date_sid AS VARCHAR(8)),1,6) = A.EXTRACT_MONTH
                                                            WHERE  A.CURR_IND=1 AND B.Last_Day_of_the_Month_Ind = 1)) AS TB1
    GROUP BY TB1.GL_REINSURANCE_CLASS_CODE,TB1.GL_Legal_ID_BK,TB1.US_SOE_Group_Code, TB1.Par_Code ) TB2
```

Output of this view is like this[image]

and the script of calling view is

```
ALTER  VIEW  [dbo].[VW_MCCSR_USNT_OUTPUT_MP] AS 
    SELECT DISTINCT V1.REPORT_NAME, V1.ROW_ITEM,
    (SELECT PAR_UL_01 FROM VW_MCCSR_FLAGS_MP WHERE CSV_GF1_PAR_UL_01_FLAG = 1)        AS PAR_UL_01,
    (SELECT NONPAR_UL_01 FROM VW_MCCSR_FLAGS_MP WHERE CSV_GF1_NONPAR_UL_01_FLAG = 1 ) AS NONPAR_UL_01,
    (SELECT PAR_UL_19 FROM dbo.VW_MCCSR_FLAGS_MP WHERE CSV_GF1_PAR_UL_19_FLAG IS NOT NULL  ) AS PAR_UL_19,
    (SELECT NONPAR_UL_19 FROM VW_MCCSR_FLAGS_MP WHERE CSV_GF1_NONPAR_UL_19_FLAG = 1 ) AS NONPAR_UL_19,
    (SELECT VUL_19 FROM VW_MCCSR_FLAGS_MP WHERE CSV_GF1_VUL_19_FLAG = 1 )             AS VUL_19,
    (SELECT UL_26 FROM VW_MCCSR_FLAGS_MP WHERE CSV_GF1_UL_26_FLAG = 1   )             AS UL_26,
    (SELECT UL_67 FROM VW_MCCSR_FLAGS_MP WHERE CSV_GF1_UL_67_FLAG = 1   )             AS UL_67,
    (SELECT UL_89 FROM VW_MCCSR_FLAGS_MP WHERE CSV_GF1_UL_89_FLAG = 1   )             AS UL_89,
    (SELECT UL_94 FROM VW_MCCSR_FLAGS_MP WHERE CSV_GF1_UL_94_FLAG = 1   )             AS UL_94,
    (SELECT VUL_94  FROM VW_MCCSR_FLAGS_MP WHERE CSV_GF1_VUL_94_FLAG = 1 )            AS VUL_94 ,
    (SELECT UL_102  FROM VW_MCCSR_FLAGS_MP WHERE CSV_GF1_UL_102_FLAG = 1 )            AS UL_102 

    FROM 
    VW_MCCSR_FLAGS_MP  V1 

    WHERE V1.ROW_ITEM = 'CSV (GF1)'
```

Comment: Since your `(select PAR_UL_01` etc fields are not linked to the actual row in the view, can't you use max() + case to get the value, instead of running select to hte same view 12 times?

Comment: You should include the actual execution plan. Based on that you can see what part(s) could be improved (through indexes, changing the sql, etc).

Comment: Simple. Get rid of the nested views. That is a sure fire way to confuse the optimizer. It seems like such a logical idea but nested views are horrible for performance. Add to that you hitting the same nested view over and over and over and you have a recipe for a performance sink hole. Grant goes into some of the details here. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/ Scroll down about half way to the nested views section.

Comment: you have a TON of what are called correlated subqueries that get run for each record in our result set in your column definitions. Better to try to join to the view once, and get what you need.

Comment: I am trying to do it in one view, using MAX() function now since it is nested view Execution plan looks so scary

Answer (score 0):

not positive but look at something like this

```
SELECT distinct PF.POLICY_SID, PF.Cash_Surrender_Value_Amt 
     , CAST(PD.GL_Legal_ID_BK AS INT) AS GL_Legal_ID_BK,PD.US_SOE_Group_Code 
     , CAST(PD.Par_Code AS INT) AS Par_Code
     , CAST(CD.GL_REINSURANCE_CLASS_CODE AS INT) AS GL_REINSURANCE_CLASS_CODE
     , TBL1.FUND_BALANCE_AMT AS SEPERATE_ACCOUNT_VALUE
FROM POLICY_FACT PF
INNER JOIN Policy_DIM PD 
        ON PF.Policy_SID = PD.Policy_SID 
INNER JOIN [VSTPODS_US].[dbo].[REF_EXTRACT_MONTH] A
        on b.DATE_SID = PF.Policy_SID
INNER JOIN [dbo].date_dim b
        ON SUBSTRING(CAST(b.date_sid AS VARCHAR(8)),1,6) = A.EXTRACT_MONTH
       AND A.CURR_IND=1 AND B.Last_Day_of_the_Month_Ind = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN  dbo.Coverage_rider_fact crf 
        ON PD.Policy_SID = CURF.POLICY_SID
.....
```